Why is e in explain, exist, etc pronounced /ɪ/?
Every dictionary I've consulted gives the pronunciation of e in "exist" as the same as the vowel in "it".
This puzzles me because I've never thought about it that way. If I were talking artificially slowly (say for clarity), I would pronounce it like the e in exit.
Why do dictionaries give it as a short i sound?

There is no reasoned explantion of numerous facts  of that sort in books on pronunciation, which is not to say that there is not a cause. // In this particular case one may hypothesize that the reason is that ɪ is easier than e to pronounce in those phonetic environments and that it matters little as far as word  recognition  goes whether it is ɪ or e; so, possibly, a shift has been made at some time for certains words of that type (from e to  ɪ), while thereafter, these words merely served as model. Just as well, it is possible that there never was such a shift and it all started with ɪ.

One reason why dictionaries give it as ɪ, and a mighty important reason it is, is that nobody except you and probably a few other individuals think of pronouncing it as e, and nobody pronounces it like that; as everybody finds  ɪ proper there is no reason to change anything, and the dictionary gives indications that are according to reality. Also, if a dictionary had too many prescriptive changes of this type it could soon be rejected as a reference that is not representative of the language.

The full OED only gives /ɛt ˈsɛtərə/ for etc., regardless of whether the written form is abbreviated or not. And they give both /ɪɡˈzɪst/ and /ɛɡˈzɪst/ for AmE exist (BrE /ᵻɡˈzɪst/ and /ɛɡˈzɪst/, which I guess just means the British 'i' in such contexts is a bit more "clipped"). Nothing much to "inrage" even the severest pedant, imho.

@LPH These are by no means “prescriptive changes”; they're merely attempting to represent a few select points along the broad continuum of natural phonetic realizations found in all unstressed syllables in English. If someone picked just one sound along that continuum stretching from a full unreduced vowel to a schwa and always used the same reduction no matter  the utterance, it would sound just as unnatural to our ears as we hear in learners who don't understand how to apply weak forms in English. It's inherent to how we speak. Dictionaries can't explain all that each time.

@tchrist I am not talking about an attempt to represent a few selective points (and I am not sure what you mean by that); instead I am talking about changing an established pattern such as the pronunciation of the grapheme e, normally /ɪ/, or perhaps more accurately, predominantly /ɪ/ in an overwhelming way, into the pronunciation /e/, that being done for the reason that a minority has /e/ or for some reason that has to do with  logical considerations of one sort or other. That shows typically a prescriptive attitude towards language. (1/2)

@tchrist In all these cases (exist, explain, expensive, experiment,…) my dictionary states that the pronunciation is /ɪ/ for both AmE and BrE, even if it also mentions the secondary  possibilities  /e/ and /ə/; but the people using /e/  are a minority, and it seems that those using /ə/ are much less in number. Swapping the place of /ɪ/ and /ə/ in that dictionary would result in indications that are not representative of the actual language, and therefore in a prescriptive dictionary. That is all I am saying. (2/2)

@LPH There is no /e/ pronunciation, only /ɛ/. You're using a dated transcription that misrepresents the lax vowel as a tense vowel.

@tchrist How could it be so? I am using the latest edition of a leading English pronunciation dictionary  (2008); could it not be, rather, that the sound is neither /e/ nor /ɛ/, and that  it is perceived differently by different people?

@LPH It can be so because dictionaries like Cambridge are still stuck foisting off an old way of writing these that no longer represents what people say. The OED uses actual IPA and says the E pronunciation is found in /ɛɡˈzɪst/,  /ɛkˈspleɪn/, /ɛkˈspɪriəns/ just as it is in /bɛt/ and /drɛs/. IPA /e/ is a tense or close vowel but /ɛ/ is a lax or open vowel. The phonemic opposition between these is critical to perceiving English words correctly, and it is a disservice to use the wrong symbol.

@tchrist For the time being, and in BrE,  /bet/ is the transcription of "bet" not only for Cambridge, but also for Collins, Longman, LPD, and Dictionary.com (this latter has also the IPA). It does in fact reflect the sound of E in a certain section of the English population (I am aware that the ɛ sound  is also found in Britain. However, according to Dictionary.com  ɛ would be nothing else than the IPA equivalent of e, which is an error (LPD's e is IPA's e̞). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel

Cambridge uses /bed/ for "bed" and /biːd/ for "bead". Different symbols for different vowels. There's no single version of the IPA for broad English transcriptions, and Cambridge's version is shown here.

Dictionaries record it that way because many people say it that way. (Although, contrary to what LPH said in a comment, pronunciations with [ɛ] also exist as a non-negligible alternative.)
The first syllable of exist, explain etc. is unstressed, and the pronunciation of vowels in fully unstressed syllables is often 'reduced'. Compare the pronunciation of the first syllable of combine (with no stress, usually pronounced as /kəm/ "cum") to that of combination (with secondary stress, usually pronounced as /kɑm/ or /kɒm/ "com").

Dictionaries are misunderstood in this. Unstressed vowels are subject to reduction that varies greatly—not just by dialect or accent but indeed even in the same speaker—from one utterance to the next based on many factors including cadence, prosody, emphasis, and surrounding phonological environment. As you mention with combination, this happens in any number of scenarios. Variable phonetics of unstressed vowels are not phonemic as they would be in stressed syllables, so these "don't count". Since it’s not a phonemic change, it doesn't change which word is generated or perceived.

Note: the noun "combine" is different (a typical initial-stress-derived noun).
